How to fix Stripe webhook integration signature failure error with aws api gateway, lambda using python?
I'm integrating the stripe webhook with my aws lambda function written in python using the api gateway. It seems I'm getting the signature error. I have tested the code locally using flask server which works perfectly fine. I checked the cloudwatch logs as well to check the similarity of the type of data for different properties. Any suggestions how can I fix the error?
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("!!!Raw event:", json.dumps(event))
    print("!!!  event.get('isBase64Encoded'): ",  event.get('isBase64Encoded'))
    payload = base64.b64decode(event['body']).decode('utf-8') if event.get('isBase64Encoded') else event['body']
    sig_header = event['headers'].get('Stripe-Signature') or event['headers'].get('stripe-signature')
    print("!!!STRIPE_ENDPOINT_SECRET:", STRIPE_ENDPOINT_SECRET)
    print("!!!Payload Type:", type(payload))
    print("!!!Payload:", payload)  # Log the payload
    print("!!!Signature Header:", sig_header)  # Log the signature header
    
    try:
        stripe_event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(payload, sig_header, STRIPE_ENDPOINT_SECRET)
        print(f"Successfully processed Stripe webhook: {stripe_event['type']}")
    except ValueError as e:
        print("ValueError:", str(e))  # Log the error
        return {
            'statusCode': 400,
            'body': json.dumps({'error': 'Invalid payload'})
        }
    except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
        print("SignatureVerificationError:", str(e))  # Log the error
        return {
            'statusCode': 400,
            'body': json.dumps({'error': 'Invalid signature'})
        }

related code in flask,
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    payload = request.data.decode("utf-8")
    # print(payload)
    event = {
        "body": payload,
        # "headers": request.headers.decode("utf-8"),

         "headers": {key: value for key, value in request.headers.items()},

        "isBase64Encoded": False
    }
    # return {"status": 200}
    return lambda_handler(event, None)



AWS Lambda can sometimes mutate the inbound request body, causing issues. See: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/issues/356 for example. Make sure what you're receiving is the raw request body. Also, verify the webhook endpoint secret you're using is the one from the dashboard and make sure it doesn't contain any extra whitespace or extra characters.

Thanks for your response. I found the problem—I made a rookie mistake. The secret I had been using was for the local environment; I didn’t realize that the secret differs for each webhook. I finally figured it out after spending quite a bit of time on it.
